# Is $X+ (X^\top)^{-1}$ invertible for invertible $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In an exercise, the following is stated:

> Define $f : \text{GL}_3(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3} : X \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(X+(X^\top)^{-1})$.
>   For a given invertible $X_1$, we iterate and create a sequence $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by: $$X_{n+1} := f(X_n).$$

This, of course, can only be when it is well-defined, which is exactly when $X+(X^\top)^{-1}$ is invertible. This is what one needs to prove.
I have a feeling I am missing something, as the things I've tried so far haven't worked; I cannot seem to find an inverse for $X+(X^\top)^{-1}$, and calculating its determinant seems too much to work out as there aren't many points awarded for solving the question. Any hints?

---

***Edit:*** as asked in a comment, here is the entire question in more detail.

- Consider the equation $x^2 -1 = 0$ for $x \in (0,\infty)$ with unique fix point $\alpha = 1$.
  Formulate Newton's fix point iteration for this problem.
- With $X_1$ an invertible diagonal matrix, prove the sequence stated above (in the question I asked) converges and give the limit of the sequence.
- With $X_1$ now an arbitrary invertible matrix, show the sequence is well-defined and give the limit.
- Writing $Q = \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$ and $H = X_1 Q^\top$ (so $X_1 = HQ$), show that $HQ$ is a polar decomposition of $X_1$.

Comment: Your iteration is a pseudo Newton method. I would be very interested in the full statement of the problem (or a precise reference). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @loupblanc, I added it to the question above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have
$$ X+(X^T)^{-1}=(X^T)^{-1}(X^TX+I)$$
and $(X^T)^{-1}$ is invertible because $X$ is.

Moreover, $X^TX$ is symmetric positive definite because $X$ is invertible, so $X^TX$ does not have $-1$ as an eigenvalue. Therefore $X^TX+I$ is also invertible, so $X+(X^T)^{-1}$ is the product of two invertible matrices and is therefore invertible.